# UK Postcode Outcode Border Data Isle of Man and Northern Ireland

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I am aware of [this](http://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes.php) as a great source for UK postcode outcode border data as KML. Unfortunately, uk postcode outcode border data for the Isle of Man (IM -> IM1, IM2 ...) and Northern Ireland (BT -> BT1, BT2 ...) are missing.

Is anyone ware of any other free data sources of UK postcode outcode border data - ideally as KML?

Comment: Northern Ireland & Isle of Man is not part of the opendata (from Ordnance Survey GB) You are after Postcode Districts? http://geolytix.co.uk/geodata/#postal-boundaries-open-2012

Comment: Duplicate post? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/970/i-need-a-kml-file-for-northern-ireland-bt-postcodes

Answer (score 1):

NISRA (Northern Ireland Statistics and Research Agency) owns the data for Norther Ireland postcodes. You will need to sign their memorandum of agreement to download it and use it:

https://www.nisra.gov.uk/support/geography/central-postcode-directory